# Imageresizer bgcolor transparancy

Tags: imageresizer

I am currently using ImageResizer from Imazen (http://imageresizing.net/)

I want to create images with the same dimensions which is easily achieved by adding the 
www.example.com/example.png?w=150&h=150

however i want to give a bgcolor to the image for background/whitespace color.

again www.example.com/example.png?w=150&h=150&bgcolor=FF00FF works perfectly. 
However is there a way to make this bgcolor transparant? (ofcourse only for .png's)

I read the docs and couldn't find a plugin or basic functionality that could provide this feature. Does anyone know if (or how) this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 6-digit hex value (RRGGBBAA) to include an alpha/transparency component.

Comment: Thanks!, example.jpg.ashx?h=70&w=70&bgcolor=FF000010&format=png (slight red transparency) works perfectly. also changed author name to Imazen.